# Puppeteer didn't reach else in if else function with JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, puppeteer

So this is the code

```
  if (
    (await page.waitForSelector("#btn")) !==
    null
  ) {
    await page.click("#btn")
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector("#element")
  }
}
```

And it didn't want to execute else part at all.
So if function should work when modal window displayed, and it works
but if modal window didnt displayed else function didnt executed.
Any ideas will be appreciated!

The second way I use it was

```
if (
    await page.waitForSelector("#btn", {
      visible: true,
    })
  ) {
    await page.click("#btn")
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector("#element", { visible: true })
  }
}
```

But result is the same? else function didnt executed, test waiting if statement.

Comment: Code looks totally fine, so a [mcve] seems needed here. Live pages are super complex so there's no telling what might be causing any behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Your using "!==" to check for a null value, I am not a javascript expert by any means but I thought !== means checking for both value and type, what if you try just using != ?  It would help to see the view you are also using.

Comment: So the test through an error `Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`, it means that test still waiting the if condition will be done

Comment: I try to use this function in this way 
 'if (
    await page.waitForSelector("#addr-validation-modal-secondary-btn", {
      visible: true,
    })
  ) {
    await page.click("#addr-validation-modal-secondary-btn")
  } else {
    await page.waitForSelector("#main_txtFirstName", { visible: true })
  }
}
'but result is the same